# CSS border and float issue

Tags: css, css-float, border, margin

I am trying to have a border whenever I hover on the element, so I created [this](http://jsfiddle.net/bSF8B/) and it works nicely for all the columns except the last column on the right.

My question is, is there anyway I can fix it without having to use `position:absolute;` on the elements? I plan to have some elements set as `display:none;` when the user clicks the toggles, so absolute positioning wouldn't work as desired as there would be 'empty blocks' instead of having the elements automatically rearranged.

PS : I also know about isotope, but I think it's quite an 'overkill' for something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if  I got your problem right, but is this behaviour what you've expected?

<strike>http://jsfiddle.net/bSF8B</strike> (sorry, wrong link)

http://jsfiddle.net/bSF8B/11/

I only forced default `border-width` to 0 and on hover cut the margins by 5px.

Comment: Design still explodes when last column is hovered

Comment: Are you sure? I've just checked this in the latest FF, IE and Chrome and it's working for me. Have you seen the right version?

Comment: No, it's OK: I was looking at the wrong link and didn't see either that it was OP link instead of your /11/ version ^^

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/PhilippeVay/bSF8B/10/

It takes into account the border that WILL exist on hover even when not hovered (border color is of the same color as the background of the parent, you can see it in the second example)

edit: border color isn't background color ^^

Answer (score 1):

I have removed the `margin` between the *blocks* and created a `border` of `5px`, *black* in color, so that when you hover over block, only the color of border changes and you do not have to *include* a new border which is actually causing the problem.

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bSF8B/13/).